# Prototyping an "object" with another "object" in Lua

Tags: lua

Considering the following code:

***http.lua***

```
local function create_socket()
    -- do stuff to create socket
    return socket, err
end


local _M
local mt = { __index = _M }


function _M:new()
    local sock, err = create_socket()
    if not sock then
        return nil, err
    end
    return setmetatable({ sock = sock, keepalive = true }, mt)
end

function _M:function1() end
function _M:function2() end

return _M
```

***http_extender.lua***

```
local http = require "http"


local _M = {}

function _M:new()
    local o = setmetatable(self, {__index = http.new()})
    return setmetatable({}, {__index = o})
end

function _M:function3() end
function _M:function4() end

return _M
```

Given that `http_extender` is meant to be a module that extends `http`'s functionality, a couple of questions:

1. I have the feeling that there is something inherently wrong with `http_extender:new()` because it is modifying `self` for each call, right?
2. If indeed wrong, what would be the correct way to do it so that each call to `http_extender:new()` creates a new `http` "object" that is composed with the functionalities and attributes of `http_extender`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this I would use something like this

```
local http = require "http"

local _M = {}

function _M:new() 

    local newob = http.new()

    local mt = getmetatable( newob )
    setmetatable( mt.__index, { __index = self } )

    return newob

end

function _M:function3() end
function _M:function4() end

return _M
```

The `_M:new()` method in this code will produce objects with functionality of both _M and the http object.

Comment: It's my understanding that this would replace the metatable set in `http.new()` and thus make the methods of `http` not accesible for `http_extender`, since  `http.new()` returns a new object with no attributes but a `__index` of `http`'s `_M`. 


Said that, I did give it a shot and effectively it does not work.

Comment: Your right I didn't notice the way the http object was set up Ill edit this answer with a correct example

Comment: I have edited my answer now _M:new() will produce objects that can access functions from http as well as its own functionality

Comment: I'm marking the answer as useful but I'll give it some time to see if there is a better solution that doesn't require copying the attributes like this.

Comment: I have edited my implementation. I don't know why I didn't think of this before. Now no attributes are copied.